# How to add helpers in own laravel packages? (Call to undefined function)

Tags: laravel, package

In my composer.json I have written:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Pmochine\\MyOwnPackage\\": "src/"
    },
    "files": [
      "src/helpers.php"
    ]
  },
```

But somehow even after composer dump-autoload the functions are not loaded. I get "Call to undefined function". To create the package I used a [package generator](https://github.com/melihovv/laravel-package-generator). Maybe it has something to do that it creates a symlink in the vendor folder?

Inside helpers I have written

```
<?php

if (! function_exists('myowntest')) {

   function myowntest()
   { 
      return 'test'; 
   }
}
```

Comment: helpers.php path?

Comment: @J.Doe it is src/helpers.php. I have the same setup like in https://github.com/keevitaja/linguist

Comment: @PhilippMochine Did you figure it out? My app cannot detect the helper autoload in composer.json. Even I run `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 5):

This is an outdated answer, the correct way is to use `composer.json`.

**Original Answer**

In the package service provider, try adding this:

```
// if 'src/helpers.php' does not work, try with 'helpers.php'
if (file_exists($file = app_path('src/helpers.php'))) { 
    require $file;
}
```

Comment: It works like with:  if (file_exists($file = __DIR__.'/helpers.php')).
But still, I'm curious why it does not detect itself, since its working for others...

Comment: This is not the correct way to do it. Use the composer.json instead.

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing is best practise and should work. I took the composer.json from barryvdh/laravel-debugbar as an example. https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/blob/master/composer.json

{

```
    "name": "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar",
    "description": "PHP Debugbar integration for Laravel",
    "keywords": ["laravel", "debugbar", "profiler", "debug", "webprofiler"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Barry vd. Heuvel",
            "email": "barryvdh@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "illuminate/support": "5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*",
        "symfony/finder": "~2.7|~3.0",
        "maximebf/debugbar": "~1.13.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\": "src/"
        },
        "files": [
            "src/helpers.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

My guess is that you are not requiring your own package the correct way in the main composer.json?

Comment: If you have the time try to generate a package with the link I've given. I'm curious if you can add helpers. But besides the helpers, everything works. I can call my facade properly and it gives me the output.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that has worked for me is to run `composer remove <vendor>/<package>` and require it back again. The files section was ignored otherwise.

This seems to happen while developing locally the package and making changes on the composer.json file.

Comment: I can confirm this. Appears that adding the file after the initial require it gets ignored even if you run `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: Indeed, `composer update <package>` and the `symlink: true` parameter will not guarantee updates to the `files` section. To do this, you need to completely remove the package `composer remove <package>` and install it again `composer req <package>`. Thank you <3

Answer (score 1):

Just need to call in your main project

```
 composer update you/your-package
```

[Source](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5520)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I was developing a local package located at `packages/provider/package/src`, I added

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            ...
        },
        "files": [
                "packages/provider/package/src/Helpers/helpers.php"
            ]
    }
```

to my app `composer.json` file and it worked.