# Creating Custom Helper Functions in within Packages Like in Codeigniter

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Am new to Laravel and i have been trying to create a helper function like i would in codeigniter within a demo package am currently developing. But, you know, being knew to the framework it seems a little bit hard to get that done as i have applied some helps i could find online to no avail.

**My Directory Structure Looks like So:**

[image: Directory Structure]

**I have just one function in the app.php file**

```php
if (! function_exists('baxi_services')) {
    function baxi_services()
    {
       $data = ['web dev', 'web design', 'SEO'];

       return json_decode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
}
```

**The composer.json file has these lines:**

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Courage\\Baxi\\": "src/"
        },
        "files": [
            "src/helpers/app.php"
        ]
    }
```

And the problem is, when i call this function in my controller like so:

```php
  return baxi_services();
```

i get the following Error:

```
Call to undefined function Courage\Baxi\Http\Controllers\baxi_services()
```

I have all ran composer dum-autoload command in my terminal but that doesnt solve the problem

Comment: Have look over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-in-laravel-5

Comment: @user3532758 yea,

Comment: @user3532758 i moved helper folder to the app directory and used the second solution provided here  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-in-laravel-5) and it worked but i really want the Helper folder to be within the package am developing

Comment: @user3532758 any suggestion?

Comment: Have a look at this link ;)  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51322978/3532758